# conditional factor demand functions for capital and labor

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, production-function

I don't how to put maths in here so using an image:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What solution are you trying to match?

Comment: @123 I matched K but could not for L(look above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(\frac{r}{w} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha})*K$$
$$\equiv (\frac{r}{w} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha})[\frac{y}{a}(\frac{w}{r} \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})^{1-\alpha}]$$
$$\equiv (\frac{r}{w} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha})^{\alpha-1+1} \frac{y}{a}$$

$$\equiv (\frac{r}{w} \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha})^{\alpha} \frac{y}{a}$$

Is that what you're looking for?  Just notice that between steps two and three, I inverted the part of K in parentheses and changed the exponent to account for the inversion.